# Why Hyper-V run Windows 10 VM as remote computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I downloaded Windows 10 free Virtual Machine from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/, extracted the VHDX file and ran it Hyper-V in my host OS Windows 10 X64 Pro. I also enable the Guest Services in Hyper-V settings to copy-paste files between host & guest.

[image: Intergation_Services]

But when I shut down the guest OS it shows a warning: "If you shut down this remote computer, no one can use it until someone at the remote location manually restarts it".

[image: remote_machine_warning]

---

**Update::** After enabling Enhanced Session Mode in Hyper-V settings, I ran `query session` command. If I do not enable that mode then remote clipboard does not work. When I disabled it the user changes to console session name.

[image: HyperV_Server_Setting]

- With Enhanced Session Mode **enabled**::

[image: with_enhanced_session]

- With Enhanced Session Mode **disabled**::

[image: without_enhanced_session]

---

Question: Why does Hyper-V run VM as remote machine? And why does this warning popup when I try to shut down the VM? Why disabling enhanced session mode makes session to console mode?

Comment: How are you accessing this VM through a console or some other means?

Comment: Just as usual with Hyper-V from virtmgmt.msc and select to connect.

Comment: Actually I don't understand why you relate integration services and the enhanced session to the question in the title. Sounds like you inserted unrelated facts here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt `"If you shut down this remote computer..."` is a result of *how* you connect to the computer, not what type of computer it is (i.e. virtual or physical).

This prompt is displayed when shutting down a computer from a session other than the target computer's console session. This would include Remote Desktop connections, which are identified as *rdp* sessions when running the `query session` command.

In your case, if you run `query session` when connected to your virtual machine I suspect you will *not* find yourself in the `console` session. This would explain why you get warned that you might not have physical access to the machine you're shutting down, hence the warning message you receive before shut down.

A console session represents the computer's *physical* interface. This is easy to identify with a physical machine; it's the keyboard/monitor/mouse. But VMs have a "physical" interface too. How you access it depends on the virtualization software, but they all have them.